# Winter spikes in SAR GRD magnitude in Middle East

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, sar

I've been looking at SAR images (GRD) of the Middle East using Google Earth Engine. I notice that in the winter time there is often spikes in the VV and VH measurements. Looking at the images themselves it seems to be an increase in intensity across almost the whole image (i.e. its not just a massive spike in one small area). Does anyone know why this might be?

I notice the spikes while looking at images of both Gaza and nearby parts of South Israel, and across all orbits. But I don't see it in Egypt.

[image: Band mean of SAR images in Gaza]

Comment: Have you checked precipitation around these dates? The moisture from recent heavy rains could shift intensity across an entire image.